# Coloring 5 Largest Numbers in Each Row and Column Yields at Least 25 Double-Colored Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

This is a question from a very old American Mathematical Monthly, if I recall correctly. It has a very nice solution and illustrates an often useful technique. If it is unsolved after a while, I will post a solution.

The integers $1,2,\ldots,225$ are arranged in a $15\times 15$ array. In each row, the five largest numbers are colored red, and in each column, the five largest numbers are colored blue. Prove that there are at least $25$ numbers colored both blue and red (purple, if you will).

Edit: Since there have been no attempts yet, I'll give a hint. Try to make the question "harder" first.

Comment: Is it true that this works for an array of any size?

Comment: yes. you should try to relax all the conditions for this problem

Comment: So for the largest n of any column or row we have at least $n^2$ purple?

Comment: Yes. More generally, if you have an $m\times n$ array with the $r$ largest in each row and $b$ largest in each column, there are at least $rb$ purple.

Comment: I actually talked with a classmate about this question and he realized that the generalized version was an old homework problem when we were freshmen a few years back. Needless to say, very few people got it, and I certainly wasn't one of the few.

Comment: Really? Your teacher either had very high expectations or just enjoyed watching students struggle :). Although the generalized version happens to be "easier" in the sense that you really have to do it in order to solve the question posed above, it's still tough.

Comment: @DennisMeng really, what class was tha, where did you take it, do you remember what book you used. Sound like a hell of a class.

Comment: @user4140 It's the second theoretical math class required for computer science students at Carnegie Mellon (CS 251). (To be fair, a couple TAs from that semester admit they went overboard on the difficulty for that particular homework. Adaptations of USAMO problems are fair game though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the hint, we will first generalize the question as follows. The integers $1, \ldots, mn$ are arranged in an $m\times n$ array. In each row, the $r \le n$ largest numbers are colored red, and in each column, the $b \le m$ largest numbers are colored blue. Prove that there are at least $rb$ numbers colored purple.

The proof of this is by strong induction on $m+n+r+b.$ Base cases are easy to check, so I will skip over them. Now, consider the largest single-colored number $x$ (if no such number exists, then we're obviously done). Without loss of generality, suppose $x$ is colored red. The column containing this number has $b$ numbers colored blue, none of which are $x,$ since $x$ is single-colored. But this means that all $b$ of these numbers are larger than $x,$ whence they must all be colored red by assumption. Hence, this column contains $b$ purple numbers.

Removing this column, we get an $m\times (n-1)$ array where in each row, at least $r-1$ of the largest numbers are colored red, and the $b$ largest numbers are colored blue in each column. By induction, this yields at least $(r-1)b$ purple numbers, so adding in the original $b$ gives $rb,$ as desired.

**Remark:** Some of you may notice that the generalized problem actually does not immediately give the result in the final paragraph, since in the subarray, we are not looking at the numbers $1,\ldots, m(n-1).$ This can be remedied easily by modifying the statement to be for $mn$ distinct real numbers.

Comment: It is easy to see why there will be rb purples when all the boxes with the single largest color are of the same colour. What I mean is is that let's say that the largest single colored box is red. Then we remove the column containing it and note that we have found b purple boxes in that column . We look at the largest single colored box in the remaining columns and again find it to be red. We remove this column and note that we have found a total of 2b purples so far. We keep doing and eventually discover rb purples . This much I understood ..cont'd below

Comment: But lets look at another case. The first largest single colored box is red and after we remove the column containing it, the largest single colored box in the remaining array is blue and so on. Basically, how do we go on to prove that we will still get r*b purple boxes even when all the single largest colored boxes after removing a column/row are not of the same colour.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal: That’s why the argument uses induction: the induction hypothesis automatically ensures that the $m\times(n-1)$ array has $(r-1)b$ purple numbers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott , I still do not get your induction argument.  Let us just look at the 15*15 case. Let us assume the following situation : largest single colored number is red. We  remove the column containing it and know that the column removed had 5 purples .. In the remaining 15*14 array, we again find the largest single colored number to be red and we again have found 5 purples ...If all such numbers are red , then it is easy to see that we will get 5*5 =25 purples. contd below.

Comment: But now, let us look at an alternate. In the same 15*15 array, we find the largest single colored number to be red. we count 5 purples and remove the column containing it, leaving us with a 15*14 array . Now, in this 15*14 array we find the largest single colored number to be blue. This blue will give us only 4 purples. How can we then guarantee that by the time we reach the 10*10 array, we would have found at least 25 purples ? I can try various permutations of finding red and blue and notice that each results in finding 25 purples but I don't want to use that approach.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal: Once you remove that column, you have a $15\times 14$ array in which every row has at least $4$ reds and every column has at least $5$ blues. By the induction hypothesis that array has at least $20$ purples. Those together with the $5$ in the column that you removed, give you $25$ purples. The induction argument does all of the work for you.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott , what are we doing an induction on ? Is it : $m+n+r+b$ ? If it is, then I am unable to follow how it is working . Because, it is not simply a question of saying, removing a column adds 5 purples . Because if a column is removed when it is a 15*15 array, then we have indeed found 5 purples. But when a column is removed from a 13*12 array, then we have only found 3 purples. P.S: I understand the following about induction very well : Prove that the statement holds for 0, or 1. Then prove that for every n, if the statement holds for n, then it holds for n + 1.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott , Another question : "Once you remove that column, you have a 15×14 array in which every row has at least 4 reds and every column has at least 5 blues. By the induction hypothesis that array has at least 20 purples." How did you figure out that the 15x14 will have at least 20 purples ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal: I simply applied the induction hypothesis: $15+14+4+5<15+15+5+5$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott , but how would you know that 15+14+4+5 will have at least 20 purples . Don't you need to know the value of 15+13+3+5 and 14+14+4+4 ? And if yes, then how do we figure out the values of 15+13+3+5 and 14+14+4+4 ? Sorry, that this discussion is stretching out so much .

Comment: @HemantAgarwal: Because the induction hypothesis guarantees that a $15\times 14$ array with at least $4$ reds in each row and $5$ blues in each column has at least $4\cdot 5=20$ purples. It says that the theorem is true for all choices of $m,n,r$, and $b$ such that $m+n+r+b<15+15+5+5$. End of story.