# Proving by induction propositions of the type $P(n_1, n_2, ..., n_k)$, where $n_1, n_2, ...,$ and $n_k$ are natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, induction

For example: I've seen proofs of the multinomial theorem that use induction in the number of terms that are elevated at some power, but none that use induction in the exponent instead of using it in the number of terms. In this case the multinomial theorem is a proposition that holds for every number of terms, and for every power ($m$ and $ n $ respectively, both being naturals).

So, the proof should use induction on$ m$ and$ n$, or is it enough to use induction on only one of them? What about if the proposition to prove is of the form $P(n_1, n_2, ..., n_k)$, with $n_1, n_2, ...,$ and $n_k $ being naturals?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can so induction on the sum of the elements, for examples of the kind of proofs see these two.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Proof_of_the_theorem

[Coloring 5 Largest Numbers in Each Row and Column Yields at Least 25 Double-Colored Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603837/coloring-5-largest-numbers-in-each-row-and-column-yields-at-least-25-double-colo)