# Proof of underlined numbers in grid

Tags: combinatorics

If $mn$ distinct numbers are entered into an $ m \times n$ board. If $k$
largest numbers in each row $(1 \leq k \leq  m)$ are underlined, and $x$ largest numbers in each
column $(1 \leq x \leq n)$ are underlined, prove that there were at least $kx$ numbers which were underlined twice.

How would I go about attacking this problem?  At first I tried a couple test cases, but was not able to determine a pattern from them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603837/coloring-5-largest-numbers-in-each-row-and-column-yields-at-least-25-double-colo?rq=1

Comment: Although it’s not obvious from the title, the answer to the linked question answers this one as well. If you prefer not to see the complete solution right away, here’s a hint: prove it by strong induction on $m+n+k+x$.